# How to see if radio button or checkbox is checked using PDFBox in Java?

Tags: java, checkbox, radio-button, pdfbox, pdf-form

I am trying to create a program that reads a PDF Form (questions and answers) and, for now, simply outputs everything back to the screen. My problem is, when I use *getValue* on radio buttons or check boxes, it always returns an empty string, no matter if it is checked or not. Is there another method I should be using? Here is my code:

```
public static void listFields(PDDocument doc) throws Exception
{
    PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm form = catalog.getAcroForm();
    List<PDField> fields = form.getFields();

    for(PDField field: fields)
    {
        String name = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
        if (field instanceof PDTextField || field instanceof PDComboBox)
        {
             Object value = field.getValueAsString();
             System.out.print(name);
             System.out.print(" = ");
             System.out.print(value);
             System.out.println();
        }
        else if (field instanceof PDPushButton)
            ;
        else
        {
            if (field instanceof PDRadioButton)
            {
                PDRadioButton radioButton = (PDRadioButton)form.getField(name);
                String value=radioButton.getValue();
                System.out.print(name);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                System.out.print(value);
                System.out.println();
                /*List<String> exportValues = ((PDRadioButton) field).getSelectedExportValues();
                for (String string : exportValues)
                {
                    name = field.getFullyQualifiedName();
                    System.out.print(name);
                    System.out.print(" = ");
                    System.out.print(string);
                    System.out.println();
                } */
            }
            else if (field instanceof PDCheckBox)
            {
                PDButton box = (PDButton)field;
                String value = box.getValue();
                System.out.print(name);
                System.out.print(" = ");
                System.out.print(value);
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\bobdu\\Documents\\SHIP_CCF_LastName_FirstName_YYYYMMDD_v1_Sample.pdf");
    PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file);
    listFields(doc);
}
```

The commented out section for radio buttons is something different I tried to see if it would change anything. The commented version and version that is executed produce the same output though. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? Can you share a file where the values have been set?

Comment: Hello @TilmanHausherr. I am using PDFBox 2.0.1, Fontbox 2.0.0, xmpbox 2.0.0, preflight 2.0.0, and pdfbox-tools 2.0.0. I do not have a file with values due to work sensitivity. I could share another PDF Form, if I could figure out to share files on here.

Comment: That is from many years ago. Use 2.0.11 for all and retry. Don't mix versions.

Comment: share files with dropbox, Google drive or sharehosters like filedropper.com

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I re-downloaded all of the PDFBox jar files. Also here is a file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0bsny97c2shp5ur/AABymi7V6yyZhl6H2UbtyPpSa?dl=0

Comment: OK, I see why this didn't work. It is a flaw in the PDF (/V value missing), but it may be a bug in PDFBox as well. How did you fill in the values? With Adobe Reader or with another tool? In the meantime I'll look how to get access to the values.

Comment: for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : radioButton.getWidgets())
                    {
                        System.out.println("AS: " + widget.getAppearanceState());
                    } same for Checkbox, but there will be only 1 widget. Look for the result that is not COSName.Off.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4256

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I'd say that first and foremost this is a bug in the PDF, according to the specification the *"**V** entry holds a name object corresponding to the appearance state of whichever child field is currently in the on state; the default value for this entry is **Off**."* Thus, *no **V** implies **Off***. Determining the value from the **AS** entries is not specified. (This implies a PDFBox bug, too, though: the default is **Off**, not empty.)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Hello. Sorry it took so long to respond I was away from the computer for the weekend. I edited the PDF with Adobe Acrobat Pro. So should I try using the _for (PDAnnotationWidget widget : radioButton.getWidgets()) { System.out.println("AS: " + widget.getAppearanceState()); }_ to see if it works?

Comment: Yes. However the metadata says that the file was created by Microsoft Word. When tried to I mark a field with Adobe Reader, then the /V entry is correctly set. Very weird.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I got it working properly. I found out that the original file was edited on a computer without Adobe Acrobat (by opening the file in Internet Explorer, editing it, then re-saving it) so when I went back and modified it myself on Adobe, it works exactly as it should. Thank you so much for all of your all's help.

Comment: @mkl from the PDF 2.0 spec (draft) need to get hold of the final version: The value of the V key shall also be the value of the AS key. If they are not equal, then the value of the AS key shall be used instead of the V key to determine which appearance to use.  Looks like we need to look at both /V and /AS - WDYT?

Comment: That formulation is in the final version, too. Very important: *the AS key shall be used instead of the V key to determine **which appearance** to use.* This is only about *showing the form*, *not* about *determining and exporting form values*.

Comment: @Maruan In particular the two sentences you quoted are new additions in ISO 32000-2. Thus, I think the very formulation has not been used by accident, *"if they are not equal, then the value of the AS key shall be used instead of the V key"* really only is meant when a viewer tries to *"determine which appearance to use"*. (In contrast to some statements in ISO 32000-1 formulated for displaying in viewers but to be interpreted for other processing types, too.) Effectively: Documents with inconsistent /V and /AS are broken, and it's ok viewers show them differently than form value extractors.

Comment: @mkl fine for me. So we return the /V content and if /V ist not set *Off*

Comment: @MaruanSahyoun That would be my proposal. At least for the 3.0 development. In the 2.x branch it might be better compatibility-wise to keep returning an empty string in case of a missing **V**. I'm not sure whether PDFBox in such cases prefers compatibility or correctness.